# What jQuery event is called right after $(document).ready()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have lots of HTML generated on `$(document).ready()`. I have a simple window system. But not only it is generated on `$(document).ready()` - also some HTML elements (different JS files put stuff into `$(document).ready()` ). I want my window system to be generated after `$(document).ready()` is called. So how do I handle a function to be called after all the code registered in `$(document).ready()` is completed?

Comment: Thats a lot of $(document).ready()! ;-)

Comment: So, you want a .ready() for your document.ready()? This isn't how jQuery works - unlike something like WordPress on PHP, due to JavaScript's event based model jQuery would have no way of 'knowing' that all the code you put into the ready() functions has completed. So, there is no event called after document.ready().  You'll need to create and wait for events to complete on your own, or use window.load().

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is another event which is fired later. it's $(window).load(); This is fired after all resources are loaded.

But perhaps you want this:

```
function loadWindowSystem(){
    // load window system here
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    // do some html stuff here

    loadWindowSystem();
})
```

This way you can separate your code in functions.

Comment: note: window.load fires when all ressources are loaded, not only images

Comment: Well this would mean that I would need to call `loadWindowSystem()` in  each document where I use $(document).ready("") to generate HTML... And also .js load will be so to say important...

Comment: Thanks Didier, I changed it in my answer.

Comment: @myWallJSON If you want to have the same functionality in multiple documents, just use one .js file and include it from various documents.

Answer (score 17):

```
  $(window).load(function(){
   //some code after ready 
  });
```

Comment: There is a lot of talk here that walks around the answer. This is the exact answer to the question asked.

Comment: $(window).load(function(){ is deprecated. Use $(window).on('load', function () { instead

Comment: For me this sometimes runs before all of my various $(document).ready calls from various scripts are complete. So it sometimes works as intended, sometimes doesn't. I'm not sure why the behavior isn't the same on every page load, maybe related to caching.

Answer (score 9):

**I usually don't advocate using `setTimeout`**, but you can build on top of @jfriend00's answer to create a more abstract approach:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(document).trigger('afterready');
    }, 1);
});

$(document).bind('afterready', function() {
    // call your code here that you want to run after all $(document).ready() calls have run
});
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want something to fire right after all `$(document).ready()` calls, you can put this once anywhere in your page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // call your code here that you want to run after all $(document).ready() calls have run
    }, 1);
});
```

This will get called along with all the other document.ready calls, but it sets a short timeout that will execute after all the other document.ready calls have finished.

Answer (score 1):

By adding another handler function ones the document is ready, the
handler will almost certainly be last one in the ready event queue. Effectively giving you an instant "post" ready handler function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // code to run "after" ready 
    });
});
```

> [$(document).ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)
>
> When multiple functions are added via successive calls to this method, they run when the DOM is ready in the order in which they are added.

Note that this will only work as long as no ones else uses this "trick".

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing after this function , so if you have some ajax loaders, only think you can do is to wait for all of them and then start rendering

EDIT But i wonder why you dont just structuralize your code to eliminate this.

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready()` is called just after the DOM has finished loading.
`pageLoad()` is called next on a 0 timer, but beware it is run after every partial postback.

Edit: Added side note - this will only count if using ASP.NET, the pageLoad functionality mentioned is separate from jQuery.  See more info [Here](http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
   alert("Window Loaded");
});
```

```
$(window).load(function(){
   alert("Window Loaded");
}
```

has been removed from jQuery.